# Swift+Cocoapods: ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'deepspeech'

Tags: swift, react-native, cocoapods

Does anyone have any idea why a RN module cocoapod would work one night then just stop working the next day despite no changes? I'm building a React Native module for DeepSpeech: https://github.com/zaptrem/react-native-transcription

Part of that is configuring the podspec with s.vendored_frameworks to use the precompiled deepspeech_ios.framework. Another part is using the cocoapods-user-defined-build-types plugin to make only my pod be treated as a dynamic_framework by cocoapods. It was working last night but all of today the compilation is failing with:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'deepspeech'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_DS_Version", referenced from:
      deepspeech_ios.DeepSpeechVersion() -> Swift.String in deepspeech_ios(DeepSpeech.o)
(Many, many more symbols with a similar issue from DeepSpeech)
```

I tried rolling back to the commit where I was certain it worked but I'm getting the same result.

I've also found that the project can't take forever to load.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and remaking the Xcode project file and deepspeech_ios.framework fixed the issue. Might have been a DeepSpeech version mismatch? Clearing the build folder is also frequently necessary when working with this library.